# How can I do event on text box in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a text box that show when I click on checkbox and I need to make an event on it that can make me bind it to object from DB

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="feture in featureEnumArray">
    <input id="txtchkFet" type="checkbox" ng-model="feture.IsChecked" />
    {{feture.DisplayText}}
    <div ng-show="feture.IsChecked" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="feture.Value" ng-change="getFeatureID(feture)" id="txtValue" placeholder="Type Feature Value" />
    </div>
    <div class="label label-danger" ng-show="feture.IsChecked && !feture.Value">
        Type Value
    </div>
</div>
```

And in Angular controller I did Like this :

```
  $scope.getFeatureID = function (feture) {
        if (feture.IsChecked) {
            $scope.Planfeature = angular.copy(feture);
            $scope.PlanFeatureTemp.FeatureID = $scope.Planfeature.ID;
            $scope.PlanFeatureTemp.Value = $scope.Planfeature.Value;
            $scope.Planfeature = [];
        }
        else {
            var index = $scope.JAdminPlan.PlanFeatureValues.indexOf(feture);
            $scope.JAdminPlan.PlanFeatureValues.splice(index, 1);
        }
        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    };
```

Comment: `that can make me bind it to object from DB`, this is pretty vague, what do you mean ? If I type some letters it will autocomplete by a match in the DB ?

Comment: I mean that I have an object from data base that contain an array

Comment: I mean that I have an object from data base that contain an array and I need to bind the value of text box to a parameter in this array , 
and the value of check box to another parameter in the same array ??

Comment: So basically, this is a form about editing the whole list at once. I choose which feature I want to edit, and I change/affect the value of it ?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean .
Please explain with examples .

Comment: Is this about modifying all the feature we pick  (checked) ?

Comment: Not modifying , adding to array inside Object from data base

Comment: so inserting a new feature ? Or all features are themselves an array of values and you want to add value in the feature ?

Comment: Look , features are Enum and have ID and other values that i don't need to add it .
I show all features from Enum and I need to add object to data base that has a relation One To Many with Features .

Comment: I show all features from Enum and I need to add object to data base that has a relation One To Many with Features .
I need to add new object with my own data and select features from Enum
the feature table in data base have column value.
I need to get this value from text box

Comment: what about add a button just next to the input with a `ng-click="postFeature(feture)"`, then in post feature you can just send the feture.featureID and the feture.Value to the server.